# datacoloumn in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

I first want to add a database column in DataColumn..and then i have to add datacoloumn in datatable.. please guide me;

```
SqlDataAdapter d2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select MARK_PARTA from  exam_cyctstmarkdet",con);
DataColumn c = new DataColumn();                      
c.ColumnName = "parta";
c.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
```

Comment: You will have to be a little bit more clear than that.

Comment: As @astander said, your question isn't clear and doesn't describe the problems you're having (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Is the bit you're missing

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable;
d2.Fill(DT);
DT.Columns.Add(c);
```

???

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a DataTable, and add your own columns to it, you can try

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add("parta", typeof(int));
```

You only have to keep a reference to the column if you plan to use it somewhere, else you can try

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add("parta", typeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataSet`, which will contain a `DataTable`. I assume you want to add the new column to this `DataTable`.

Here's how to do that:

```
SqlDataAdapter d2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select MARK_PARTA from  exam_cyctstmarkdet",con);
DataSet dst = new DataSet();
d2.Fill(dst); // now you have a populated DataSet containing a DataTable
DataTable dt = dst.Tables[0]; // I created this variable for clarity; you don't really need it

DataColumn c = new DataColumn();                      
c.ColumnName = "parta";
c.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");

dt.Add(c);
```

After you add the `Column` to the `DataTable`, the `Column` will be empty.

You can populate it in code.